# Efficient Data Structure for TimeZone.knownTimeZoneIdentifiers?

Tags: arrays, swift, tree

I have an array of Strings returned from `TimeZone.knownTimeZoneIdentifiers` that I would like to parse into a nested dictionary (or another data structure).

The format of the `[String]` is

> ["Africa/Abidjan", "Africa/Accra",..,"America/Araguaina","America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires", ...,"Pacific/Marquesas", "Pacific/Midway", "Pacific/Nauru"]

The end result would be something like

```
["Africa":["Abidjan":[], "Accra":[]], "America": ["Araguaina": [], "Argentina": ["Buenos_Aires"]], "Pacific": ["Marquesas":[], "Midway":[], "Nauru":[]]]
```

I will need to query all of the keys at each level of the dictionary.

There must be another way to do this functionally or with recursion, rather than `split(seperator: "/")` and several for loops to build the data structure manually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use a dictionary for this. Make a custom type. In particular, you are describing a *tree*. Let's make one (largely based on https://github.com/raywenderlich/swift-algorithm-club/tree/master/Tree, and if there is more that you need to do, modify the Node class itself to meet your needs):

```
class Node<T> {
    var value: T
    weak var parent: Node?
    var children = [Node<T>]()
    init(_ value: T) {
        self.value = value
    }
    func add(_ node: Node<T>) {
        children.append(node)
        node.parent = self
    }
}
```

Now it's trivial:

```
let ids = TimeZone.knownTimeZoneIdentifiers
let root = Node("")
for id in ids {
    var node = root
    let splits = id.split(separator: "/").map(String.init)
    for split in splits {
        if let child = node.children.first(where:{$0.value == split}) {
            node = child
        } else {
            let newnode = Node(split)
            node.add(newnode)
            node = newnode
        }
    }
}
```

Okay, let's see what we've got. It will be useful to have a nice way of printing a node:

```
extension Node: CustomStringConvertible {
    private func display(level:Int) -> String {
        let offset = String(repeating: " ", count: level * 4)
        var s = offset + String(describing: value)
        if children.isEmpty { return s }
        s += " {\n"
        s += children.map { $0.display(level:level+1) }.joined(separator: ",\n")
        s += "\n\(offset)}"
        return s
    }
    var description: String { return display(level:0) }
}
```

Now:

```
root.children.forEach {print($0)}
```

Result:

```
Africa {
    Abidjan,
    Accra,
    Addis_Ababa,
    Algiers,
    Asmara,
    Bamako,
    Bangui,
    Banjul,
    Bissau,
    Blantyre,
    Brazzaville,
    Bujumbura,
    Cairo,
    Casablanca,
    Ceuta,
    Conakry,
    Dakar,
    Dar_es_Salaam,
    Djibouti,
    Douala,
    El_Aaiun,
    Freetown,
    Gaborone,
    Harare,
    Johannesburg,
    Juba,
    Kampala,
    Khartoum,
    Kigali,
    Kinshasa,
    Lagos,
    Libreville,
    Lome,
    Luanda,
    Lubumbashi,
    Lusaka,
    Malabo,
    Maputo,
    Maseru,
    Mbabane,
    Mogadishu,
    Monrovia,
    Nairobi,
    Ndjamena,
    Niamey,
    Nouakchott,
    Ouagadougou,
    Porto-Novo,
    Sao_Tome,
    Tripoli,
    Tunis,
    Windhoek
}
America {
    Adak,
    Anchorage,
    Anguilla,
    Antigua,
    Araguaina,
    Argentina {
        Buenos_Aires,
        Catamarca,
        Cordoba,
        Jujuy,
        La_Rioja,
        Mendoza,
        Rio_Gallegos,
        Salta,
        San_Juan,
        San_Luis,
        Tucuman,
        Ushuaia
    },
    Aruba,
    Asuncion,
    Atikokan,
    Bahia,
    Bahia_Banderas,
    Barbados,
    Belem,
    Belize,
    Blanc-Sablon,
    Boa_Vista,
    Bogota,
    Boise,
    Cambridge_Bay,
    Campo_Grande,
    Cancun,
    Caracas,
    Cayenne,
    Cayman,
    Chicago,
    Chihuahua,
    Costa_Rica,
    Creston,
    Cuiaba,
    Curacao,
    Danmarkshavn,
    Dawson,
    Dawson_Creek,
    Denver,
    Detroit,
    Dominica,
    Edmonton,
    Eirunepe,
    El_Salvador,
    Fort_Nelson,
    Fortaleza,
    Glace_Bay,
    Godthab,
    Goose_Bay,
    Grand_Turk,
    Grenada,
    Guadeloupe,
    Guatemala,
    Guayaquil,
    Guyana,
    Halifax,
    Havana,
    Hermosillo,
    Indiana {
        Indianapolis,
        Knox,
        Marengo,
        Petersburg,
        Tell_City,
        Vevay,
        Vincennes,
        Winamac
    },
    Inuvik,
    Iqaluit,
    Jamaica,
    Juneau,
    Kentucky {
        Louisville,
        Monticello
    },
    Kralendijk,
    La_Paz,
    Lima,
    Los_Angeles,
    Lower_Princes,
    Maceio,
    Managua,
    Manaus,
    Marigot,
    Martinique,
    Matamoros,
    Mazatlan,
    Menominee,
    Merida,
    Metlakatla,
    Mexico_City,
    Miquelon,
    Moncton,
    Monterrey,
    Montevideo,
    Montreal,
    Montserrat,
    Nassau,
    New_York,
    Nipigon,
    Nome,
    Noronha,
    North_Dakota {
        Beulah,
        Center,
        New_Salem
    },
    Nuuk,
    Ojinaga,
    Panama,
    Pangnirtung,
    Paramaribo,
    Phoenix,
    Port-au-Prince,
    Port_of_Spain,
    Porto_Velho,
    Puerto_Rico,
    Punta_Arenas,
    Rainy_River,
    Rankin_Inlet,
    Recife,
    Regina,
    Resolute,
    Rio_Branco,
    Santa_Isabel,
    Santarem,
    Santiago,
    Santo_Domingo,
    Sao_Paulo,
    Scoresbysund,
    Shiprock,
    Sitka,
    St_Barthelemy,
    St_Johns,
    St_Kitts,
    St_Lucia,
    St_Thomas,
    St_Vincent,
    Swift_Current,
    Tegucigalpa,
    Thule,
    Thunder_Bay,
    Tijuana,
    Toronto,
    Tortola,
    Vancouver,
    Whitehorse,
    Winnipeg,
    Yakutat,
    Yellowknife
}
Antarctica {
    Casey,
    Davis,
    DumontDUrville,
    Macquarie,
    Mawson,
    McMurdo,
    Palmer,
    Rothera,
    South_Pole,
    Syowa,
    Troll,
    Vostok
}
Arctic {
    Longyearbyen
}
Asia {
    Aden,
    Almaty,
    Amman,
    Anadyr,
    Aqtau,
    Aqtobe,
    Ashgabat,
    Atyrau,
    Baghdad,
    Bahrain,
    Baku,
    Bangkok,
    Barnaul,
    Beirut,
    Bishkek,
    Brunei,
    Calcutta,
    Chita,
    Choibalsan,
    Chongqing,
    Colombo,
    Damascus,
    Dhaka,
    Dili,
    Dubai,
    Dushanbe,
    Famagusta,
    Gaza,
    Harbin,
    Hebron,
    Ho_Chi_Minh,
    Hong_Kong,
    Hovd,
    Irkutsk,
    Jakarta,
    Jayapura,
    Jerusalem,
    Kabul,
    Kamchatka,
    Karachi,
    Kashgar,
    Kathmandu,
    Katmandu,
    Khandyga,
    Krasnoyarsk,
    Kuala_Lumpur,
    Kuching,
    Kuwait,
    Macau,
    Magadan,
    Makassar,
    Manila,
    Muscat,
    Nicosia,
    Novokuznetsk,
    Novosibirsk,
    Omsk,
    Oral,
    Phnom_Penh,
    Pontianak,
    Pyongyang,
    Qatar,
    Qostanay,
    Qyzylorda,
    Rangoon,
    Riyadh,
    Sakhalin,
    Samarkand,
    Seoul,
    Shanghai,
    Singapore,
    Srednekolymsk,
    Taipei,
    Tashkent,
    Tbilisi,
    Tehran,
    Thimphu,
    Tokyo,
    Tomsk,
    Ulaanbaatar,
    Urumqi,
    Ust-Nera,
    Vientiane,
    Vladivostok,
    Yakutsk,
    Yangon,
    Yekaterinburg,
    Yerevan
}
Atlantic {
    Azores,
    Bermuda,
    Canary,
    Cape_Verde,
    Faroe,
    Madeira,
    Reykjavik,
    South_Georgia,
    St_Helena,
    Stanley
}
Australia {
    Adelaide,
    Brisbane,
    Broken_Hill,
    Currie,
    Darwin,
    Eucla,
    Hobart,
    Lindeman,
    Lord_Howe,
    Melbourne,
    Perth,
    Sydney
}
Europe {
    Amsterdam,
    Andorra,
    Astrakhan,
    Athens,
    Belgrade,
    Berlin,
    Bratislava,
    Brussels,
    Bucharest,
    Budapest,
    Busingen,
    Chisinau,
    Copenhagen,
    Dublin,
    Gibraltar,
    Guernsey,
    Helsinki,
    Isle_of_Man,
    Istanbul,
    Jersey,
    Kaliningrad,
    Kiev,
    Kirov,
    Lisbon,
    Ljubljana,
    London,
    Luxembourg,
    Madrid,
    Malta,
    Mariehamn,
    Minsk,
    Monaco,
    Moscow,
    Oslo,
    Paris,
    Podgorica,
    Prague,
    Riga,
    Rome,
    Samara,
    San_Marino,
    Sarajevo,
    Saratov,
    Simferopol,
    Skopje,
    Sofia,
    Stockholm,
    Tallinn,
    Tirane,
    Ulyanovsk,
    Uzhgorod,
    Vaduz,
    Vatican,
    Vienna,
    Vilnius,
    Volgograd,
    Warsaw,
    Zagreb,
    Zaporozhye,
    Zurich
}
GMT
Indian {
    Antananarivo,
    Chagos,
    Christmas,
    Cocos,
    Comoro,
    Kerguelen,
    Mahe,
    Maldives,
    Mauritius,
    Mayotte,
    Reunion
}
Pacific {
    Apia,
    Auckland,
    Bougainville,
    Chatham,
    Chuuk,
    Easter,
    Efate,
    Enderbury,
    Fakaofo,
    Fiji,
    Funafuti,
    Galapagos,
    Gambier,
    Guadalcanal,
    Guam,
    Honolulu,
    Johnston,
    Kiritimati,
    Kosrae,
    Kwajalein,
    Majuro,
    Marquesas,
    Midway,
    Nauru,
    Niue,
    Norfolk,
    Noumea,
    Pago_Pago,
    Palau,
    Pitcairn,
    Pohnpei,
    Ponape,
    Port_Moresby,
    Rarotonga,
    Saipan,
    Tahiti,
    Tarawa,
    Tongatapu,
    Truk,
    Wake,
    Wallis
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this reply and included link. This is the answer I was hoping for. Nicely done.

Comment: Note that all I did was suggest a nice form of _storage._ I have not shown how to _search_ the tree efficiently, because I don't know what you ultimately want to do with it (you didn't say). But you are free to modify the "back end" so that the tree works more efficiently, depending on your needs. It's the _idea_ of the tree that I'm proposing here.

Comment: Improved the `description` output.

Comment: I'd like to search the tree by
1. listing all root elements
2. listing all child elements for a specified node
3. listing all parent nodes for a specified leaf element (for instance, searching Buenos_Aires will return America > Argentina > Buenos_Aires) ultimately I need to find the knownTimeZoneIdentifier for any specified leaf node
The user is presented with a series of UITableViews to drill down until a timeZoneIdentifier is selected.

Comment: BTW the link is returning a 404, but I'm familiar with raywenderlich and found this which I believe you intended to link https://www.raywenderlich.com/1053-swift-algorithm-club-swift-tree-data-structure

Comment: Cool, then the nested arrays implementation I've suggested is exactly what you want. The arrays are ordered and indexed exactly as you need for table views, and you can reconstruct the identifier from a leaf thanks to the `parent` property. — I'll fix the 404, thanks.

Comment: Thanks to @matt for the follow up here https://stackoverflow.com/a/65164239/463172

Answer (score 2):

You can use `reduce(into:)` and populate your dictionary using Key-based subscript default value:

```
let dictionary: [String: [String]] = TimeZone.knownTimeZoneIdentifiers.reduce(into: [:]) {
    if let index = $1.firstIndex(of: "/") {
        $0[.init($1[..<index]), default: []].append(.init($1[$1.index(after: index)...]))
    }
}
```

---

Then you can map your dictionary values. If you find the slash append to the array otherwise set an empty collection to the key.

```
let result = dictionary.mapValues { string -> [String: [String]] in
    string.reduce(into: [:]) {
        if let index = $1.firstIndex(of: "/") {
            $0[.init($1[..<index]), default: []].append(.init($1[$1.index(after: index)...]))
        } else {
            $0[$1] = []
        }
    }
}
```

---

If you would like to do that in a single pass:

```
let result: [String: [String:[String]]] = TimeZone.knownTimeZoneIdentifiers.reduce(into: [:]) {
    if let index = $1.firstIndex(of: "/") {
        let key = String($1[..<index])
        let value = String($1[$1.index(after: index)...])
        if let index = value.firstIndex(of: "/") {
            let country = String(value[..<index])
            let city = String(value[value.index(after: index)...])
            $0[key, default: [:]][country, default: []].append(city)
        } else {
            $0[key, default: [:]][value] = []
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
result.forEach({print("key:",$0.key, "values:", $0.value)})
```

Comment: Thank for your the quick reply and updates. This works well.

Comment: @emdog4 you are welcome. If you need the corresponding  timezones you can add a tuple to the end instead of just the a string `(city: String, identifier: String)` and when setting the values `$0[key, default: [:]][country, default: []].append((city,$1))`
           `} else {`
                `$0[key, default: [:]][value] = [(value,$1)]` this way you can easily initialize a timezone when accessing the values.