# How can I build a recursive function in Swift to return a String?

Tags: swift, recursion

I have a Node class defined as follows. `value: T` is a `String`

```
class Node<T> {
    var value: T
    weak var parent: Node?
    var children = [Node<T>]()
    init(_ value: T) {
        self.value = value
    }
    func add(_ node: Node<T>) {
        children.append(node)
        node.parent = self
    }
}
```

I'd like to build a function to return a String of the current Node's value and all Parent values. Ideally, the function would be defined in the class. For example,

```
currentnode.listAllValues()
would return -> "/parent2value/parent1value/currentnodevalue"
```

So far the following function works with a simple `print()`, and I've also considered using an `inout` parameter.

```
func listAllValues(node: Node<String>) {
    print(node.value)
    if node.parent?.value != nil {
        listAllValues(node: node.parent!)
    }
}
```

Comment: So you want to recurse up the hierarchy but print the hierarchy from the top down?

Comment: Hi @matt, yes. I believe you helped me with this initially https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62364443/efficient-data-structure-for-timezone-knowntimezoneidentifiers

Comment: LOL that is the answer I was going to refer you to!!!!!

Comment: Perhaps I should have just added another comment there? I'm still not clear how to do it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
func desc(_ s:String? = nil) -> String {
    var me = String(describing:self.value)
    if let prev = s {
        me += "/" + prev
    }
    return self.parent?.desc(me) ?? me
}
```

Example:

```
let n = Node("hey")
n.add(Node("ho"))
n.children.first?.add(Node("nonny nonny no"))
let start = n.children.first!.children.first!
print(start.desc())
```

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this with an instance method which calls itself on the parent node first, if there is one:

```
func listAllValues() -> String {
    if let p = parent {
        return "\(p.listAllValues())/\(value)"
    } else {
        return "/\(value)"
    }
}
```

Or as an obfuscated one-liner:

```
func listAllValues() -> String {
    return "\(parent?.listAllValues() ?? "")/\(value)"
}
```

Example:

```
let p2 = Node("parent2value")
let p1 = Node("parent1value") ; p2.add(p1)
let n = Node("currentNodeValue") ; p1.add(n)

print(n.listAllValues())
// --> /parent2value/parent1value/currentNodeValue
```